# DataStax/Cassandra USING TIMESTAMP behavior is unpredictable when a new timestamp value equals to previous one

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, datastax, cql

This behavior in Cassandra seems undocumented and counterintuitive. I want to know why this is happening and how to prevent such things.

Create a test table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_table (id text PRIMARY KEY, foo text);
```

Now create a row in the table with `USING TIMESTAMP`.

```sql
INSERT INTO test_table (id, foo) 
VALUES ('first', 'hello') 
USING TIMESTAMP 1566912993048082;
```

The result is

```
 id    | foo   | writetime(foo)
-------+-------+------------------
 first | hello | 1566912993048082
```

Now let's update the row using the same timestamp.

```sql
INSERT INTO test_table (id, foo) 
VALUES ('first', 'hello2') 
USING TIMESTAMP 1566912993048082;
```

Everything works fine.

```
 id    | foo    | writetime(foo)
-------+--------+------------------
 first | hello2 | 1566912993048082
```

Let's update the row again using the same timestamp.

```sql
INSERT INTO test_table (id, foo) 
VALUES ('first', 'hello1') 
USING TIMESTAMP 1566912993048082;
```

!!! Nothing changed.

```
 id    | foo    | writetime(foo)
-------+--------+------------------
 first | hello2 | 1566912993048082
```

Update the same row again.

```sql
INSERT INTO test_table (id, foo) 
VALUES ('first', 'hello3') 
USING TIMESTAMP 1566912993048082;
```

!!! Works again.

```
 id    | foo    | writetime(foo)
-------+--------+------------------
 first | hello3 | 1566912993048082
```

It seems like an update happens only in cases when `old.foo < new.foo` using the same timestamp.

Expected results:

- update doesn't happen using the same timestamp
- update **always** happens using the same timestamp

Actual result:

- update **sometimes** happens using the same timestamp

Comment: What is your client CF setting? Is it the same session for both reading and writing? Are the settings the same for reading/writing? Is it possible you're querying a node that isn't getting updated? How many nodes in the cluster? More than one? Are the times in sync? Just some ideas.

Comment: I'm using cqlsh with the following configuration. [cqlsh 5.0.1 | DSE 6.7.4 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | DSE protocol v2]. The cluster has 6 nodes. I'm not sure that the problem with a cluster, because the problem is persistent, doesn't matter how many times I'm trying to reproduce it the result is always the same.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to think in my head how this would even work. In reality this would never occur - the same data multiple time with the exact same timestamp. If the record exists in multiple sstables with the same exact timestamp, I'm not sure how cassandra handles that. Very good question. I'll play around a bit. What would be a good test is to redo what you're doing and flush the data after every insert. Review the sstables. Data should be in multiple sstables. See what your query results are. Run it over and over. I would guess the results would be random, as you state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FYI,

I opened a ticket to get the answers to your question. Here is the response for others that may try this. Again, in a typical situation, one wouldn't do what you're doing.

---- Response ----

As you are aware, DSE/Cassandra handles the conflicts via the write timestamp where the latest always wins. In the event of the tie as detailed in your thought experiment, there are actually two scenarios that need to be handled.

Live cell colliding with tombstone
In this situation the tombstone will always win. There is no way to know if that is what the client expects, but the behavior will be consistent.

Live cell colliding with another live cell
Similar to the tombstone situation, we have no way of knowing which cell should be returned. In order to provide consistency, when the write timestamps are the same, the larger value wins.